# How to get the item seleced from a FragmentList when in another Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Say I have a FragmentList with 10 options and when clicked it takes me to another Fragment.  How would I be able to get the item selected in that list of 10 in the new Fragment?  Post code if possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195026/1443717).

you can call the FramgmentManager and get any Fragment by id, then get any publically stored variables. example: what option was selected. [example of getting Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

or possibly get the `getSelectedItemId()` from the ListFragment in that Fragment